# System.IO VB.NET, Mover archivos en una unidad de red

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-server, system.io

## Preguntar original

Muy buen día.

Estoy moviendo manipulando archivos de una unidad de red usando **System.IO.File.Copy**.

En mi **entorno de Desarrollo** no me da ningún problema, pero en el servidor de aplicaciones me aparece:

> *Excepción no controlada por la aplicación*

.

He revisado que los usuarios pertenezcan al grupo propietario o mínimo tengan los **permisos necesarios**.

Ahora estoy preguntándome si es alguna característica o manipulación del servidor de aplicaciones que necesita ser activada, algo como para convertirlo en un **servidor de archivos**. Mi servidor es **Windows R2**.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

## Seguimiento 1

Con el animo de ser mas descriptivo, el proceso es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **Visor de eventos**

Active la auditoria de la carpeta en el servidor para poder obtener la siguiente información en el visor de eventos:

Código de evento: **3005**

- Código de evento: **3005**
- Mensaje de evento: **Se ha producido una excepción no controlada**.
- Secuencia de eventos: **137**
- Ocurrencia de evento: **1**
- Código de detalle del evento: **0**
- Nivel de confianza: Completo

Información de excepción:

**- Tipo de excepción**: InvalidOperationException

- **Mensaje de excepción**: mostrar un cuadro de diálogo modal o un
  formulario cuando la aplicación no se está ejecutando en modo
  UserInteractive no es una operación válida. Especifique el estilo
  ServiceNotification o DefaultDesktopOnly para mostrar una
  notificación de una aplicación de servicio.

Me parece que es algo respecto al uso del MsgBox pero si fuera algo relacionado a los usuarios espero me puedan decir.

Feliz dia.

## Seguimiento 2

Luego de arreglar lo del MsgBox, obtuve los siguientes mensajes capturados del try catch.

**StackTrace**:

- at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
  maybeFullPath)
- at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj)
- at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
- at Mover(Ruta1, Ruta2) in Trasladar.aspx.vb:line 29

Encuentro que se debe hacer alguna de las siguientes cosas:

1. **Abrir IIS → configuración avanzada** para el grupo de aplicaciones en cuestión y cambiar la identidad para que se ejecutara en el servicio de red como administrador → Aceptar. "cmd -> iisreset", lo que me preocupa de esta opción es en términos de seguridad, que la solicitudes se ejecutarían como administrador.
2. **Usar DirectorySecurity**: para luego agregarlo en la creacion del directorio,Directory.CreateDirectory(path, securityRules);

Hasta el momento tengo la carpeta compartida, con permisos para cierto grupo, pero su comportamiento me parece extraño, ya que pasa lo siguiente al ejecutarlo en el mismo ordenador con privilegios de administrador:

1. Si ejecuto desde VS en local, me funciona correctamente.
2. Si ejecuto desde web me aparece dicho problema.

En **síntesis** lo que me parece debo hacer es solucionar el problema de acceso denegado que da al ejecutar la instrucción desde el cliente ya que en local funciona.

## Seguimiento 3

Revisando el tema del acceso denegado, me encontré con lo siguiente:
[Descripción de identidades en IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/understanding-identities).

Donde se explica las **identidades** con las que se ejecutan las solicitudes de un cliente.

Por defecto al crear un grupo de aplicaciones se crea una cuenta virtual "**ApplicationPoolIdentity**" y esta cuenta tiene privilegios mínimos. En mi caso esa identidad es la que tengo asignada, en la siguiente imagen pueden ver un ejemplo de donde ver esta información.

[image: IIS Manager]

Para poder tener acceso a recursos de red, la cuenta debería de ser una de tipo "**Network Service**". Por lo que podría cambiarla por esa identidad. Pero al ser una identidad con mas privilegios, quiero ver que vulnerabilidades debo cubrir antes de cambiarla.

Comment: Que tal si primero controlas la excepción, la pones en los logs, o la escribes en un archivo físico, y **una vez que sepas EXACTAMENTE qúe está ocurriendo** buscamos una solución juntos?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Comprendo que pude no explicarme de la mejor manera. Respecto de lo que dice @Arriel, estoy capturando con Try catch, únicamente el mensaje, pero le agregue StackTrace, Message, Source y GetHashCode, para ver que información puedo obtener de ellos. 

Los cambios los puedo probar solo cuando hay datos y eso seria una ves por día. Yo me preguntaba si el servidor tenia que activar cierta características o configuraciones para permitir ser un servidor de archivos.

Por ahora esperare a ve la información que resulta de el try catch.

Comment: Agrega mayor detalle al LOG, de lo contrario, estamos yendo a ciegas. Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: tu app se esta ejecutando como servicio en el servidor?

Comment: Y otra cosa.. no deberias poder probarla una vez por mes.. armate un entorno que simule tu servidor...

Comment: @gbianchi, comprendo, pero los recursos del ordenador de trabajo son bajos, virtualizar me supone un problema.

Comment: @fredyfx, por lo que entendi del problema es el siguiente: 

Estoy tratando de mostrar un cuatro de dialogo **ON SERVER** en el lado cliente, pero no va a mostrar ninguno el navegador, y no muestra los mensajes generados en el servidor. Por lo que lo solucionan usando js para mandar alertas.

Lo malo es que la funcionalidad de aceptar o rechazar el reemplazo queda nula por el momento y tengo que buscar una alternativa.

Comment: no entiendo nada ._.

Comment: yo tampoco... que tipo de app es???

Comment: y probar no tiene nada que ver con virtualizar... siempre debes poder armar un entorno para probar.. estas probando en produccion....

Comment: Es un sistema viejo hecho en VB.NET WCF.

Comment: Está en un servidor local, y como solo da clavo en el de producción, por eso solo pruebo cuando hay datos en el, pero con la auditoría de las carpetas pude obtener el error y ahora solo falta probarlo la otra semana.

Comment: @fredyfx mi problema parece ser de las identidades asignadas al grupo de aplicaciones https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/understanding-identities

Comment: @gbianchi, es un VB.NET 4 WCF, comprendo lo de la virtualizacion, pero los equipos no tienen las prestaciones suficientes para esa tarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Seguimiento 4

Para no dejar a nadie que vea esto con la duda y pueda ayudarle, les describo lo siguiente:

### Solución

1. Utilizar la suplantacion, mediante [Impersonate](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8).
2. Crear un usuario para uso exclusivo de la aplicacion.
3. Darle permisos a dicho usuario a los recursos compartidos.

Pueden hacer una clase de prueba y llevar un seguimiento del usuario activo con el que se les identifica, para esto pueden utilizar:

> ```
> Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
> ```

Pueden investigar:

> WindowsImpersonationContext

Espero les ayude.